# Visual Studio 2015 Installer extention cannot get dependencies of a DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dependencies, installation

I have a Visual Studio 2015 project and I want to package it in an installer. I searched for some options and the most simple should be using the Visual Studio Installer plugin. I've seen several tutorials (although this process is very much straightforward) and I get stuck on the same part every time.

One of the DLLs I use in this project is breaking the build process of the Installer (the build process of the normal project is fine). I am getting the following message:

```
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: MountainTop, Configuration: Debug ------
ERROR: Unable to update the dependencies of the project.  The dependencies for the object 'FestaJsonConnectorSupportDotNet.dll' cannot be determined.
```

Not sure why Visual Studio can't find the dependencies of this one but can still compile the normal project. Also, I have tried to Exclude this specific DLL from the Detected Dependencies of the Installer project, but while building it still tries to get the library dependencies for this particular one.

Any idea why I am having problems with this particular library and how I can bypass it (maybe create an installer without it and manually paste it in the programs folder after the install)?

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem with VS2017. Our solution was to open the .vdproj file and manually remove all the FILE sections containing the filename in the errors. For example, if the object name in the error is FILENAME, remove this section:

```
    "{9F6F8455-1EF1-4B85-886A-4223BCC8E7F7}:_DA245F337D3A391A509F6F85ABC85543"
    {
    "AssemblyRegister" = "3:1"
    "AssemblyIsInGAC" = "11:FALSE"
    "AssemblyAsmDisplayName" = "8:EntityFramework.FILENAME, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL"
        "ScatterAssemblies"
        {
            "_DA245F337D3A391A509F6F85ABC85543"
            {
            "Name" = "8:EntityFramework.FILENAME.dll"
            "Attributes" = "3:512"
            }
        }
    "SourcePath" = "8:EntityFramework.FILENAME.dll"
    "TargetName" = "8:"
    "Tag" = "8:"
    "Folder" = "8:_4ECC3E8786B14EE68F744E24DD8EEFB9"
    "Condition" = "8:"
    "Transitive" = "11:FALSE"
    "Vital" = "11:TRUE"
    "ReadOnly" = "11:FALSE"
    "Hidden" = "11:FALSE"
    "System" = "11:FALSE"
    "Permanent" = "11:FALSE"
    "SharedLegacy" = "11:FALSE"
    "PackageAs" = "3:1"
    "Register" = "3:1"
    "Exclude" = "11:FALSE"
    "IsDependency" = "11:TRUE"
    "IsolateTo" = "8:"
    }
```

Comment: worked for me for Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects!